# Create an application that creates others applications by click

Tags: c#, exe

I would like to know  if I can create a new process (*.exe) from source code files  by clicking in a button? For example.

```
    private void cmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         Application.Create("test.exe");  //Create a new application
     }
```

And if I can write a code in the new application before it's published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53ezey2s)** to initialize a new process.

EDIT: If you want to execute your code on the fly to create a new process,  please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx

Comment: I cant write that..Their is not Process and Start() method

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() you have to import the namespace

Comment: Oh, I have import, So with this class I can run a process, but its not my question, I want to create another application, like Process.CreateAplication("teste.exe") in desktop.